# Holt's Winter Exponential Smoothing and LSTM? Some reference

Tags: machine-learning, time-series, forecasting, references, statsmodels

Can you refer me a book, a site, or a PDF that can show a step by step guide for forecasting LSTM and Holt's winter Exponential Smoothing in a univariate data?